# C#: If listbox has a certain word delete that item?

Tags: c#, listbox, for-loop

How to make a for loop that if a listbox has an item that for example has the word `"hi"` in it it will delete it?

I started working with this but it didnt work:

```
 if (listBox6.Items.ToString() == " ")
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < listBox6.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
     {
          listBox6.Items.Remove(listBox6.SelectedItems[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: show us what you got... we can't edit invisible code for you. For starters we don't know whether you are doing ASP, ASP.Net, AJAX, MVC, WPF or Winforms (naming _just_ the popular kinds)

Comment: @sehe, whats ASP and AJAX got to do with this?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: precisely my point; it _could_ have had everything to do with it, but we weren't told. (In case you missed the point, [System.Web.UI.WebControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bhzsw6t.aspx) has different controls than [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753382(v=vs.85).aspx) and a Ajax databinding situation would lead to very different code for any framework).

Comment: Hmmm I played around with my code and I think this should work:          for (int i = 0; i < listBox6.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        listBox6.Items.Remove(listBox6.Items.ToString() == " ");
                    }

Comment: I don't think the post was that bad as to warrant excessive down votes. If the guy is a new user, kindly pointing out that his question was not properly phrased would help him to contribute to the community in a positive way in the future... :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this....

Iterate using an index, starting at the last item:

```
for (int n = listBox1.Items.count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
{
    string removelistitem = "HI";
    if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions!
Use Regex.match to find the word your looking for and then remove the item from the listbox. something like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
{
  string input = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"hi", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {

         listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i--);

    }

}
```